# How do I access the registers with python in gdb

Tags: python, gdb

How can I access the cpu registers of in the current debugged instance? From gdb you can call for example `printf "0x%x", $eax` and `set $eax_b = $eax` is there also a way to do this via the python support gdb gives? Or should I create a python function which can be call like `save-reg "eax" $eax` which on his hand stores the registers in an array where I want them to be stored?

On the other hand, with gdb script you can also `set $eax = 1000` for example, this I would also like to do from within a python script, instead of a gdb script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't believe the Python API to GDB offers *direct* access to the registers, but depending on what you want to do with it you can access it either by evaluating the gdb command with `gdb.execute()`, or evaluate the `"$eax"` expression with `gdb.parse_and_eval()`:

```
(gdb) p $rbx
$23 = 140737488348072
(gdb) python print type(gdb.parse_and_eval("$rbx")), gdb.parse_and_eval("$rbx")
<type 'gdb.Value'> 140737488348072
```

(This example is at the gdb prompt, but the `gdb` module isn't any different in other code executed in GDB.)

Comment: I don't think it's in there aether, but this will do the trick I guess! Thanks!

Comment: Well, `parse_and_eval` really is the workhorse for any Python code embedded in GDB. There isn't any other way because the way that's there already works :)

Comment: @ThomasWouters I dont get it :s how does the chosen answer explain to do the following using python? `set $eax = 1000`

Comment: I found the answer to setting a gdb variable using python [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885923/redirecting-storing-output-of-shell-into-gdb-variable/6889615#6889615). Now I get what @ThomasWouters meant when he mentioned `gdb.execute()` in his answer :)

Comment: Depending on your python version it might be `python print(type(gdb.parse_and_eval("$rbx")), gdb.parse_and_eval("$rbx"))`.

Comment: "There isn't any other way because the way that's there already works". No, the Python API is incomplete. I've been having to read the C code to figure out how GDB commands are implemented and then backsolve to see whether interfaces exist in Python. It's unacceptably incomplete, and _very_ unusable to boot.

Answer (score 5):

Recent `gdb` versions (like Debian 7.12-6) have a `read_register` method in the `gdb.Frame` class.

```
(gdb) info register rip
rip            0x7f68656c142d       0x7f68656c142d <__lll_lock_wait+29>
(gdb) python print(gdb.selected_frame().read_register('rip'))
0x7f68656c142d <__lll_lock_wait+29>
(gdb)
```

That class has no corresponding method to modify a register value. It makes sense for that method to belong to that class because register values differ across stack frames, in the sense that `gdb` shows saved register values in outer frames, such as the ones returned by the `older` method, callers of the inner frames.