# How to store the output of a gdb command into a variable?

Tags: shell, unix, gdb

I'm trying to store the output of a gdb command into a gdb variable. I'm following the instruction from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885923/redirecting-storing-output-of-shell-into-gdb-variable). But when I print the variable it shows empty.

My **pop_stack** file contains this

```
20
268435372
```

I use the following command to store the value **268435372** from the **pop_stack** into gdb variable **$pop_ele**. And try to print the value as hexadecimal. But the **$pop_ele** shows empty.

```
(gdb) shell echo set \$pop_ele=\"$(tail -n 1 pop_stack)\"
(gdb) p/x $pop_ele
```

output:

```
set $pop_ele="268435372"
$8 = 0x0
```

My desire output for **p/x $pop_ele** command is **0xfffffac**

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With gdb 8.X, possible to use `shell` and `source` to execute commands that depends on external data.

```
shell echo set \$pop_ele=$(tail -n1 pop_stack) > gdb.tmp
source gdb.tmp
```